# Make image fill div proportionally and center image vertically

Tags: jquery, css

If anyone has used InDesign before, when you have an image placed inside a frame, right-clicking on the frame will allow you to select a *Fill Frame Proportionally* option so the entire frame contains the image and any overflow is hidden, then after that you can *Center Content*.

How can this effect be achieved within the browser?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I've create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9NNxT/) that helps achieve this result.

However, this will cause the image to expand larger than its resolution if the `div.frame` width is greater than the width of its image.

Assuming the following HTML

```
<div class="frame">
    <img src="http://stuffpoint.com/parrots/image/240658-parrots-white-parrot.jpg" />
</div>
```

This would have the following styles applied

```
.frame {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.frame img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Obligatory jQuery to center the image vertically on load and on resize

```
$(function(){
    centerImageVertically();
    $(window).resize(function() {
        centerImageVertically();
    });
    function centerImageVertically() {
        var imgframes = $('.frame img');
        imgframes.each(function(i){
            var imgVRelativeOffset = ($(this).height() - $(this).parent().height()) / 2;
            $(this).css({
                'position': 'absolute',
                'top': imgVRelativeOffset * -1
            });
        });
    }
});
```

**UPDATE:** an alternative way of structuring the JavaScript above:

```
    $(function () {
        var centerImageVertically = function () {
            var imgframes = $('.frame img');
            imgframes.each(function (i) {
                var imgVRelativeOffset = ($(this).height() - $(this).parent().height()) / 2;
                $(this).css({
                    'position': 'absolute',
                    'top': imgVRelativeOffset * -1
                });
            });
        };

        centerImageVertically();
        $(window).resize(centerImageVertically);
    });
```